# make full <li> block to behave as link

Tags: html, css

I have the following `<li>` and I would like the whole `li` to behave as a link. Currently, only the text in the span acts as a link. Also, is it possible to change the colour of the text on hover. My code only changes the colour of the text when I hover over it, but stays the same when I hover elsewhere in the block. Any help is appreciated.

I've put the demo on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/noscirre/JtVGp/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

http://jsfiddle.net/Bongs/JtVGp/5/

I've added class to the link and some css to `li` and the link...

HTML

```
<li class="app1"> 
  <a title href="#" class="blocklink">
        <span>ANOTHER APP</span>
  </a> 
</li>
```

CSS

```
.app1 {position:relative;}
.blocklink{position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;width:100%;height:100%;}​
```

Comment: Please add your code to the body of the answer. If jsfiddle goes down your answer is useless.

Comment: Why not wrap the li in <a> </a> ?

Comment: @Playmaker You can do so BUT `li` is a block-level element, while `a` is an inline element. As a good practice it is not recommended to have a block-level element inside inline element. :)

Comment: @Bongs - Actually you can't wrap `<li>` in `<a>` since there can not be any elements inbetween `<ul>` and `<li>` and because of what you already said :)

Comment: This doesn't work if there is more than one li element because they overlap each other due to the absolute position.

Answer (score 1):

With respect to the changing color, change your last CSS entry from

```
#app-container ul.apps li:hover a:hover { color: #fff; }
```

to

```
#app-container ul.apps li.app1:hover a { color: #fff; }
```

To make the whole `<li>` box behave like a link, you can add an `onclick` handler via JavaScript to it, e.g., like this:

```
var li = document.querySelector( '#app-container .app1' );

li.addEventListener( 'click', function(){
   window.location = 'your/new/url';
} );
```

and maybe change the cursor attribute by using `cursor: pointer` ([MDN link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/cursor)).

Comment: @joesavage to make a whole `<li>` element behave like a link, I don't know another way.

Comment: I should think switching the 'li' to a mere wrapper and then making the 'a' do the brute of the work and styling would do the trick, but I haven't heavily examined the source.

Comment: Why not wrap the li in <a> </a>

Comment: @Playmaker Because `<li>` is the only content allowed under a `<ul>`. See, e.g., at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/ul).

Comment: Oh alright, but this is while using a DTD right? Cause it does work otherwise. Will keep in mind for future!

Comment: @Playmaker It is not limited to usage of a DTD, but is part of the standard. Reason, why it seems to work, is, that browser try to make the best of your code even if it is wrong with respect to the standard.

Comment: Oh ok. Just for further clarification, standard or convention?

Comment: @Playmaker Standard. See, e.g., [here @WHATWG](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-ul-element).

Answer (score 0):

Simply add this style to your navigation:

```
ul.menu > li > a {
    display: block;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

This solution does not consider a span tag inside. The HTML looks like this:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li><a>Navigation Point 1</a></li>
    <li><a>Navigation Point 2</a></li>
</ul>
```